# How to parse oracle jdbc ezconnect with python

Tags: python, oracle, parsing, jdbc

I've tried to search ways how to parse with python an oracle jdbc string which can be in different formats, but didn't find anythng.

Problem:

Input string can be based on different patterns:

- jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname.example.ru:1521/database.example.ru
- jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:DATABASE

I cannot predict what pattern I get next time. So I need to use some package which always able to parse such string to not implement one more bicycle.

### Update_#0

Still not found any package which could parse connection string on parts without actually connecting to oracle.

For now, I wrote regex for parsing jdbc oracle ezconnect strings, you can use this to parse ezconnect:

`^jdbc:oracle:thin:((?'username'[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})([\/](?'password'[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})){0,1}){0,1}@((\/\/){0,1}(?'hostname'[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]*)(\:(?'port'\d+)){0,1})(\/(?'service_name'[a-zA-Z\.\-0-9]{1,}(\:(?'server_type'[a-zA-Z]{1,})){0,1}){0,1}(\/(?'instance_name'[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})){0,1}){0,1}$`

This is an expanded query:

```
^
    jdbc:oracle:thin:
    (
        (?'username'[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})
        ([\/]
            (?'password'[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})
        ){0,1}
    ){0,1}
    @
    (
        (\/\/){0,1}
        (?'hostname'[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]{1,})
        (\:(?'port'\d+)){0,1}
    )
    (\/
        (?'service_name'[a-zA-Z\.\-0-9]{1,}
            (\:
                (?'server_type'[a-zA-Z]{1,})
            ){0,1}
        ){0,1}
        (\/
            (?'instance_name'[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})
        ){0,1}
    ){0,1}
$
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/) on this lines:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname.example.ru:1521/database.example.ru
jdbc:oracle:thin:@sales-server
jdbc:oracle:thin:@sales-server:3456
jdbc:oracle:thin:@sales-server/sales
jdbc:oracle:thin:@sales-server:80/sales
jdbc:oracle:thin:@sales-server/sales:dedicated/inst1
jdbc:oracle:thin:@sales-server//inst1
jdbc:oracle:thin:@sales-server:1521/sales.us.acme.com
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//sales-server/sales.us.acme.com
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//sales-server.us.acme.com/sales.us.oracle.com
jdbc:oracle:thin:wat@//sales-server.us.acme.com/sales.us.oracle.com
jdbc:oracle:thin:wat/wat@//sales-server.us.acme.com/sales.us.oracle.com
jdbc:oracle:thin:wat/wat@//sales-server.us.acme.com/sales.us.oracle.com:dedicated/instance
jdbc:oracle:thin:wat/wat@//sales-server.us.acme.com//instance
jdbc:oracle:thin:@non-ezconnect-string-test:1521:DATABASE
```

### Update_#1

This code is for python:

```
import re

jdbc_ezconnect = re.compile("^jdbc:oracle:thin:((?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})([\/](?P<password>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})){0,1}){0,1}@(?P<ezdb_name>((\/\/){0,1}(?P<hostname>[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]{1,})(\:(?P<port>\d+)){0,1})(\/(?P<service_name>[a-zA-Z\.\-0-9]{1,}(\:(?P<server_type>[a-zA-Z]{1,})){0,1}){0,1}(\/(?P<instance_name>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})){0,1}){0,1})$", re.MULTILINE)

text = [
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname.example.ru:1521/database.example.ru",
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@sales-server",
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@sales-server:3456",
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@sales-server/sales",
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@sales-server:80/sales",
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@sales-server/sales:dedicated/inst1",
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@sales-server//inst1",
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@sales-server:1521/sales.us.acme.com",
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//sales-server/sales.us.acme.com",
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//sales-server.us.acme.com/sales.us.oracle.com",
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:wat@//sales-server.us.acme.com/sales.us.oracle.com",
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:wat/wat@//sales-server.us.acme.com/sales.us.oracle.com",
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:wat/wat@//sales-server.us.acme.com/sales.us.oracle.com:dedicated/instance",
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:wat/wat@//sales-server.us.acme.com//instance",
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:DATABASE"
]

matches = jdbc_ezconnect.search(text[0])

username = matches.group('username')
password = matches.group('password')
ezdb_name = matches.group('ezdb_name')
hostname = matches.group('hostname')
port = matches.group('port')
service_name = matches.group('service_name')
server_type = matches.group('server_type')
instance_name = matches.group('instance_name')


print username, password, ezdb_name, hostname, port, service_name, server_type, instance_name
```

Outputs:

`None None //hostname.example.ru:1521/database.example.ru hostname.example.ru 1521 database.example.ru None None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've read oracle docs about EZCONNECT syntax and wrote regex to parse it.
The second string is a short version of standard jdbc pattern so i unified those regexp strings within one class to parse each variant.

So here's jdbc connection string parser:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re


class JDBCParserError(Exception):
    pass


class JDBCParser:
    """
    Класс для распарсивания jdbc-строк.
    """

    # ezonnect patterns
    jdbc_ezconnect = re.compile("^jdbc:oracle:thin:"
                                "((?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})"
                                "([\/](?P<password>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})){0,1}){0,1}"
                                "@"
                                "(?P<ezdb_name>((\/\/){0,1}"
                                "(?P<hostname>[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]{1,})"
                                "(\:(?P<port>\d+)){0,1})"
                                "(\/(?P<service_name>[a-zA-Z\.\-0-9]{1,}"
                                "(\:(?P<server_type>[a-zA-Z]{1,})){0,1}){0,1}"
                                "(\/(?P<instance_name>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})){0,1}){0,1})$")

    # jdbc standard pattern - host:port:sid
    jdbc_classic = re.compile("^jdbc:oracle:thin:"
                              "((?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})"
                              "([\/](?P<password>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})){0,1}){0,1}"
                              "@"
                              "(?P<connection_string>("
                              "(?P<hostname>[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+)"
                              "(\:(?P<port>\d+)))"
                              "(\:(?P<service_name>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)))$")

    username = None
    password = None
    ezdb_name = None
    hostname = None
    port = None
    service_name = None
    instance_name = None

    connection_string = None

    def __init__(self, jdbc_string):
        ezconnect_match = self.jdbc_ezconnect.search(jdbc_string)
        classic_match = self.jdbc_classic.search(jdbc_string)

        if ezconnect_match or classic_match:
            if ezconnect_match:
                self.username = ezconnect_match.group('username')
                self.password = ezconnect_match.group('password')
                self.ezdb_name = ezconnect_match.group('ezdb_name')
                self.hostname = ezconnect_match.group('hostname')
                self.port = ezconnect_match.group('port')
                self.service_name = ezconnect_match.group('service_name')
                self.instance_name = ezconnect_match.group('instance_name')
            if classic_match:
                self.username = classic_match.group('username')
                self.password = classic_match.group('password')
                self.connection_string = classic_match.group('connection_string')
                self.hostname = classic_match.group('hostname')
                self.port = classic_match.group('port')
                self.service_name = classic_match.group('service_name')
        else:
            raise JDBCParserError("JDBC string not recognized")
```